# How to import macros in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust, glium

I'm struggling with how to import macros from an external crate. In my main.rs I'm importing the Glium crate:

```
#![macro_use]
extern crate glium;

pub use glium::*;

// where my actual main function will be done from
mod part01drawtriangle;

fn main() {
    part01drawtriangle::main();
}
```

In my other file, where my main function is coming from, I call one of the macros from that crate:

```
pub fn main() {
    implement_vertex!(Vertex, position);
}
```

When building, I get the error message:

```
error: macro undefined: 'implement_vertex!'
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with the same problem, also with glium, but trying to apply the solution below doesn't work. I keep getting the macro undefined error. My directory structure is [main.rs, lib.rs, tutorial: [ mod.rs, draw_triangle.rs ]] where the implement_vertex! is being used in draw_triangle.rs

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`#[macro_use]`, not `#![macro_use]`.

`#[..]` applies an attribute to the thing after it (in this case, the `extern crate`).  `#![..]` applies an attribute to the *containing* thing (in this case, the root module).

Comment: but then I got errors like this `failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `glium::glutin::WindowBuilder` 

is that namespace related? I've also added `use glium::*;` but still doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like a brittle macro.  Try adding `use glium;` to the top of `part01drawtriangle.rs`.

Comment: You might want to open an issue with the crate; the solution is to use `$crate::` instead of `glium::` in the macro definition.

Answer (score 20):

According to [the Rust Edition Guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/macro-changes.html):

> In Rust 2018, you can import specific macros **from external crates** via `use` statements, rather than the old `#[macro_use]` attribute.

```
// in a `bar` crate's lib.rs:
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! baz {
    () => ()
}

// in your crate:
use bar::baz;

// Rather than:
//
// #[macro_use]
// extern crate bar;
```

> This only works for macros defined in external crates. For macros defined locally, `#[macro_use] mod foo;` is still required, as it was in Rust 2015.

Comment: As of March 2022, macro_export exports to the root, and the macro can be used with 'use crate::baz'.

Answer (score 1):

If using a macro exported by a library and imported by a binary within the same project then use the following pattern.

From `lib.rs` that is part of the `[lib]` definition within `Cargo.toml`

```rust
// src/lib/lib.rs

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! my_macro {
    // ...
}
pub use my_macro;
```

From the client file `bin.rs` that is part of the `[[bin]]` definition within `Cargo.toml`

```rust
// src/bin/bin.rs

use crate::my_macro;
```

Each imported macro needs it's own single `use` statement. Multiple items cannot be imported along with the macro (those need a separate `use` statement).