# How to import/use macro from different module in the same crate?

Tags: rust, import, macros, export, visibility

###### Real life scenario:

I wanted to use `crate::app::verbose_trace!("string literal")` inside `crate::app::args::parse` module.

###### Reproducable scenario:

After an hour of attempts, I came with following simple example.
It exposes my misunderstanding of macros.

```
  #[macro_use]
  mod foo{
      pub fn bar(){
          println!("bar works")
      }
      #[macro_export]
      macro_rules! baz{
          ()=> {println!("baz works")}
      }
  }

  fn main(){
      foo::bar();
      foo::baz!();
      // Following doesn't work either:
      // use foo::baz;
      // baz!();
  }
```

Compiler complains

```
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `baz` in `foo`
  --> src\main.rs:14:14
  |
  14 |         foo::baz!();
  |              ^^^ could not find `baz` in `foo`
```

as if it was utterly blind :0

###### I read:

- https://riptutorial.com/rust/example/5647/exporting-and-importing-macros
- and partially:

  - [How do you import macros in submodules in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175953/how-do-you-import-macros-in-submodules-in-rust)
  - [How to import macros in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612392/how-to-import-macros-in-rust)

###### I would like to see:

- A compilable version of my example.
- Explanations why it did failed to compile.
- Optionally:

  - Some other suggestions how to use marco in submodule/supermodule.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`#[macro_export]` exports the macro **under the crate root**. Thus, `crate::baz!()` will work, but `foo::baz!()` won't (and you don't need `#[macro_use]`, it is for using the macro in another crates).

If you want to export the macro *in this path*, for crate local macros don't use `#[macro_export]` as all. Instead, export the macro like:

```rust
macro_rules! baz {
    () => {
        println!("baz works")
    };
}
pub(crate) use baz;
```

For exporting the macro for use in other crates you still need `#[macro_export]`:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! baz {
    () => {
        println!("baz works")
    };
}
pub use baz;
```

This will export the macro both under the crate root and under `foo`.

Comment: is there a way to avoid exporting from the crate root but export from the current module in a way that other crates can use? I have a secenario where exporting at the crate root will cause conflicts between several modules

Comment: @SamJohnson Not with `macro_rules`, unfortunately (only with macros 2.0). But you can use a trick: export a macro with `#[doc(hidden)]` mangled name (e.g. `module__macro`), then reexport it with public name from the module.

Comment: @SamJohnson E.g. `#[macro_export] #[doc(hidden)] macro_rules! foo__bar { ... } pub use foo_bar as bar;`.